# Why is my Angular Mat-Autocomplete element not showing options?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using auto complete so users can select a company that exists in the connectwise service and save it.

My issue is when I begin typing a company that I know exists, mat-autocomplete does not show any options.

For troubleshooting, I have added a *ngFor that shows the connectwise data is coming through the application and is working.

component code

```
  companyConnectwiseNameControl = new FormControl();
  filteredOptions: Observable<ConnectwiseCompany[]>;

  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CompanyModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { company: CompanyConnection, isNewCompany: boolean },
    private connectwiseService: ConnectwiseService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // If data is available and it's not a new company, pre-populate the form fields
    if (this.data) {
      this.companyConnectwiseNameControl.setValue(this.data.company.connectWiseId);
    }

    this.filteredOptions = this.companyConnectwiseNameControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      switchMap(value => this.filterOptions(value))
    );
  }

  filterOptions(value: string): Observable<ConnectwiseCompany[]> {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    this.connectwiseService.getConnectwiseCompanies().pipe(
      map(companies => companies.filter(company =>
        company.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
      ))
    ).subscribe(companies => {
      companies.forEach(company => {
        console.log(company.name);
      });
    });
    

    return this.connectwiseService.getConnectwiseCompanies().pipe(
      map(companies => companies.filter(company =>
        company.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
      ))
    );
  }
```

component html

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="dialog-content">
  <h2>Edit Company Connection</h2>

  <h1>Datto Domain: {{ data.company.dattoDomain }}</h1>
  
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>ConnectWise Company Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput [formControl]="companyConnectwiseNameControl" autocomplete="off">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async">
        {{ option.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div>
  <div *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async">
    {{ option.name }}
  </div>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <div style="margin-left: auto">
    <button mat-button class="cancel" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-button [disabled]="!formValid()" (click)="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't see the mat-options element, but I do see the span elements update when I enter something in the input field or when filterOptions gets triggered.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you also need to add

```
  [matAutocomplete]="auto"
```

in your input. So it'd be:

```
<input matInput 
  [formControl]="companyConnectwiseNameControl" 
  [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
  autocomplete="off">
```

This binds input to the <mat-autocomplete #auto> control